# Why can't i use std:cin as an argument

Tags: c++, iostream

learning c++ and can't understand why I can't use "std::cin" as an argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
int doubleNumber(int a)
{
    return 2 * a;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cout << doubleNumber(std::cin >> x);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::cin >> x` returns a reference to `cin`, which isn't implicitly convertible to `int`.

You can use the `,` operator like so:

```
(std::cin >> x, x)
```

to first run `std::cin >> x` and then evaluate that expression to `x`.

```
#include <iostream>
int doubleNumber(int a)
{
    return 2 * a;
}

int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cout << doubleNumber( (std::cin >> x, x) );
    return 0;
}
```

Splitting it will probably into two lines will probably make it more readable, though.

In any case `std::cin >> x` can be used as an expression.
E.g., it's common to have streams implicitly converted to booleans to check whether they're in a succeeding (good) state. (E.g., `if(std::cin >> x){ //...`)

Comment: thank you so much, that was exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You presumably want to pass `x`. But the result of `cin >> x` is `cin`, not `x`.

The solution is easy

```
 std::cin >> x;
 std::cout << doubleNumber(x);
```

You can't actually pass `cin` if you did want to because it's a stream, not an `int`.

And the return type of `>>` is the way it is in order to allow things like `std::cin >> x >> y >> z;` to work.

Comment: so there is no way to pass the cin >> x as an argument, you will always need to to ask before using it as an argument?

Comment: Can not the function take a parameter of stream type?  (just askin' :).

Comment: @MartinJames Devils advocate, eh' ;-P

Comment: @MartinJames You can pass anything if the argument type matches.

Comment: @MartinJames Of course. (By reference, normally.) But that would require changing the function definition, which did not seem to me to be the sense of the question.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cin` is a global object and `operator >>`, which you are calling is a method that returns `std::cin` again, so you can write things like:

```
std::cin >> x >> y;
```

What I am trying to say is that the output of `std::cin >> x` is not the value you just typed in, as you seem to expect, but `std::cin` itself.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt for further details.